# Error type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'num' in type cast flutter sqflite

Tags: string, flutter, dart, sqflite

I use following code for search in sqflite database

```
    Future<Albums> getAlbumSearch([String search]) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    // specify the column names you want in the result set
    List<Map> maps =

    await dbClient.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $TABLE WHERE $TITLE LIKE '%${search}%' ");

    Albums allAlbums = Albums();
    List<Album> albums = [];
    if (maps.length > 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < maps.length; i++) {
        albums.add(Album.fromJson(maps[i]));
      }
    }
    allAlbums.albums = albums;
    return allAlbums;
}
```

but it gives me this error in app:Error type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'num' in type cast

How can I solve this?

My Album and Albums class

```
    class Album {
    Album();

    num albumId;
    num id;
    String title;
    String url;
    String thumbnailUrl;

    factory Album.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json) => _$AlbumFromJson(json);
    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$AlbumToJson(this);
}
```

```
    class Albums {
    Albums();

    List<Album> albums;

    factory Albums.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json) => _$AlbumsFromJson(json);
    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$AlbumsToJson(this);
}
```

Comment: What does your `Albums` look like? Looks like there is a datatype mismatch.

Comment: @Pro post edited.See there please

Comment: What is the parameter that you're passing to `getAlbumSearch`? Could it be `num` instead of `String`?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I think this code may be vulnerable to SQL Injection. The impact might not be so severe if it's running on the users own machine (if it's running on a shared backend server, it would) but it's worth fixing. You can test it by entering a search term that contains a quote (like `test's`) and it'll likely throw.

Comment: @DannyTuppeny it will be in user side

Comment: @Pro I used string value

Comment: @ShahriarNasimNafi that lessens the security impact but it's still an issue you should consider addressing (even if only to prevent your app crashing if the user types apostrophes into the search).

Comment: Yes app crashes in some case.It is in development.Practice work for flutter.@DannyTuppeny